# What is the difference between require('d3') and require('d3-selection')

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

I'm writing a javascript application in nodejs and noticed something strange.
I am passing a d3 selection to a function (example)

```
// mymodule.js
exports.myfunc = function(ele){
  if(ele instanceof d3.selection){
    // do something
  } else {
    // throw error
  }
}

// main.js
mymodule = require('mymodule');
var ele = d3.select('#myElement');
mymodule.myfunc(ele);
```

In main js if i say `var d3 = require('d3')` the if `ele instanceof d3.selection` fails.  However if in main.sj I require `'d3-selection'` the test passes.

What is the difference between `require('d3')` and `require('d3-selection')`?

My package.json looks like

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies":{
    "d3":"^4.12.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d3-selection` is simply a `d3`'s sub node module.

`d3` is a node module and it isn't instance of `d3-selection`. that's how the condition fail. You can NOT call `d3-selection` from an `d3` instance

`d3-selection` is another module and is `d3`'s sub module. That's why you can use `d3.selection` .

So these are identical:

1:

```
// mymodule.js
exports.myfunc = function(ele){
  if(ele instanceof d3.selection){
    // do something
  } else {
    // throw error
  }
}

// main.js    
var d3 = require('d3')
mymodule = require('mymodule');
var ele = d3.selection.select('#myElement');
mymodule.myfunc(ele);
```

2:

```
// mymodule.js
exports.myfunc = function(ele){
  if(ele instanceof d3.selection){
    // do something
  } else {
    // throw error
  }
}

// main.js    
var d3Selection = require('d3-selection')
mymodule = require('mymodule');
var ele = d3Selection.select('#myElement');
mymodule.myfunc(ele);
```

Comment: Is there a more correct way to test if ele is an instance of?

Answer (score 0):

d3-selection is a set of standalone D3 microlibraries. ([Read more](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection))

```
if(ele instanceof d3.selection){
   // do something
}
```

In the above block you must be using some functionality very specific to the D3 microlibraries and hence when you just import d3 it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

d3-selector is a micro-librery inside d3 also known as module. For you to use the  modules inside the d3 package like d3-selection you have to imported [npm d3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3) at the end of the doc you can see the sample.

When you use only required d3 you are not inside the d3-selection module, that is why you are not able to use any function that are declared inside the d3 selection [d3 selection docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection)